# como puedo validar si existe un rango ya registrado

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, intellij-idea, java-11

¿Cómo puedo validar si existe un rango ya registrado?

Por ejemplo:
Tengo un el rango registrado 1-99 de un producto,
y el usuario quiere registrar del mismo producto este otro rango 2-25 pero
este rango 2 a 25 ya están contenidas en 1-99

Entonces mi método que es para registrar precio de compra de un producto,
es la siguiente:

```java
public void setSaveProductPurchasePrice(ProductPurchasePrice purchasePrice, ProductPurchasePriceRequestDto priceRequestDto){      
  if(priceRequestDto.getMinQuantity() > priceRequestDto.getMaxQuantity()){
     throw new BusinessRuleException(messageUtil.getMessageByCode(COUNT_MIN_CONSTRAINT));
  }
  purchasePrice.setIncoterms(incoterms);
  purchasePrice.setProduct(product);
  purchasePrice.setSupplier(supplier);
  purchasePrice.setCurrency(currency);
  purchasePrice.setPrice(priceRequestDto.getPrice());           
  purchasePrice.setMinQuantity(priceRequestDto.getMinQuantity());
  purchasePrice.setMaxQuantity(priceRequestDto.getMaxQuantity());
  Optional<ProductPurchasePrice> validatedMinAndMax = productPurchasePriceRepository.findValidate(priceRequestDto.getProductId(),
     priceRequestDto.getIncotermId(), priceRequestDto.getSupplierId(), priceRequestDto.getMinQuantity(), priceRequestDto.getMaxQuantity());
  if (validatedMinAndMax.isPresent()) {
     throw new BusinessRuleException(messageUtil.getMessageByCode(PRODUCTS_CONSTRAINT_EXISTS));
  }

  if(priceRequestDto.getMinQuantity() < priceRequestDto.getMaxQuantity() &&
                        priceRequestDto.getMaxQuantity() > priceRequestDto.getMinQuantity()) {
    throw new BusinessRuleException(messageUtil.getMessageByCode(COUNT_RANK_CONSTRAINT));
  }

  productPurchasePriceRepository.save(purchasePrice);
}
```

---

Como se observa tengo seteando los campos, luego tengo un *Optional* para validar que exista el `produc/incote/prove/rango(getMinQuantity,getMaxQuantity).`

y después tengo un if que valida si las cantidades mínimas y las cantidades máximas están contenidas en el rango que ya ha sido registrado `"produc/incote/prove/rango(getMinQuantity,getMaxQuantity)"`

Aquí hay una imagen donde si cumple la validación ya que esta dentro del mismo rango.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ingreso una cantidad *min* y *max* diferente a la del rango ya registrado sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje, cuando debería registrarse.

Aquí hay una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podría ser, me falta alguna validación?

**Imágenes de ayuda**

Comment: `if all([x in range(1,99) for x in range(2,25)]): print("yes")` :)

Comment: Lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y aumenten las posibilidades de obtener una respuesta. No coloques etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver

Comment: Buenas, Jorge, bienvenido al sitio. No se entiende bien qué quieres exactamente y en el código expuesto no aparecen varios rangos. Describe aunque sea en pseudocódigo a qué te refieres, cuales son los rangos que hay que comprobar, que información tiene el elemento que quieres testear y cuales es la salida esperada. Varios casos, si puede ser. Y como indica Christian, ¿porqué has usado las etiquetas php, python y jdeveloper si estás usando java y las capturas de pantalla parecen de IntelliJ? Además el IDE usado parece no tener nada que ver con la pregunta.